# Change default feature layer color when displaying popup

Tags: arcgis-js-api

So, I have an ESRI map with my popup being displayed onclick with custom data in the popup.  I'm not 100% sure what I need to do in order to change the color on the selected state while the popup is being displayed.  Right now it's green.  I'd like to change this to another color.

I've tried using a SimpleFillSymbol over the top of state onclick but I feel there has to be a way to configure this.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Habq5.png)

Comment: Apart from tagging the software/framework, it would be helpful for users if you add it to the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I find the answer soon after posting the question.  If using a MapView, you can specify the highlightOptions.

```
var view = new MapView({
  map: webmap,
  container: "viewDiv",
  highlightOptions: {
     color: [255,255,255,0]
  }
});
```

https://community.esri.com/thread/253433-how-to-change-or-remove-selection-colour-in-415